# How does "break;" work in async function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was using pbkdf2-password module in my login process, and some of those code seems been stuck while running. I used async hashing function to verify users, and problem happens when user inputs wrong passwd. Just loading doesnt stop.

I tried redirecting and return when user inputs wrong passwd and it worked.
but I want to know why the break didnt work.

```
app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  let userid = req.body.id;
  let password = req.body.password;
  console.log('userid = ', userid);
  console.log('password = ', password);
  console.log('userlist = ', sampleUserList);
  let bFound = false;

  for (let i = 0; i < sampleUserList.length; i++) {
    let user = sampleUserList[i];
    console.log(sampleUserList[i]);
    if (userid === user.userid) {
      console.log('[found] userid = ', userid);
      bFound = true;
      /* here's where I verify users. */
      return hasher({
        password: password,
        salt: user.salt
      }, function(err, pass, salt, hash) {
        if (err) {
          console.log('ERR : ', err);

        }

        if (hash === user.password) {
          console.log('INFO : ', userid, ' logged in successfully')

          req.session.user = sampleUserList[i];
          req.session.save(function() {
            res.redirect('/carlist');
          })
          return;
          /* here's the code for when users input wrong passwd but still have ID */
        } else {
          console.log('Wrong passwd.');
        }
      });
    }
    if (bFound) break;
  }

  if (!bFound) {
    console.log('Theres no such ID.');
  }
  res.redirect('/login_form');
});

else {
  console.log('Wrong passwd.');
  res.redirect('/login_form');
  return;
}
```

Problem solved with this code but I want to know why the break didnt work.

```
no error msg but infinite loading.
```

Comment: You do realise when bFound is set to true, you return from that function, so, of course the `if (bFound) break;` will never happen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `break` will never be reached. The `return` inside the if statement will prevent all subsequent code from executing.

It also breaks out of the loop, so you can feel free to remove `break`, your function already does what you intended the `break` to do.

```
app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  let userid = req.body.id;
  let password = req.body.password;
  let bFound = false;

  for (let i = 0; i < sampleUserList.length; i++) {
    let user = sampleUserList[i];
    if (userid === user.userid) {
      bFound = true;
      return hasher(/* args */); // <-- this ends execution of the login handler
    }
    if (bFound) break;
  }

  if (!bFound) {
    console.log('Theres no such ID.');
  }
  res.redirect('/login_form');
});
```